# How to avoid closing channel with catch exception (Kotlin/Flow)

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

```kotlin
fun View.clicks(
    scope: CoroutineScope,
    error: Throwable.() -> Unit = {},
    block: (view: View) -> Unit,
) =
    callbackFlow {
        setOnClickListener(this::offer)
        awaitClose {
            setOnClickListener(null)
        }
    }
        .throttleFirst(1000)
        .onEach { block(it) }
        .catch { error(it) }
        .launchIn(scope)
```

`block` throw some exception, then channel been closed and `awaitClose` execute.
How to avoid closing channel.
`catch` is useless

Comment: Have you tried using a SupervisorScope?

Comment: I use 'viewModelScope' which consist of SupervisorJob()

Comment: I see, what about a simple  `onEach { runCatching { block(it) }.exceptionOrNull()?.let { it.error() } }`

Comment: This is definitely a weird usage of callbackFlow. I would consider a different approach for debouncing buttons..